# UI controls difference between WP8 and WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1

I have worked on WP7 app development(C# and XAML). I need to work on a windows phone 8 app development. I googled on what are all the API difference between WP7 and WP8 SDKs, especially I want to know whether there are any changes in UI controls available in WP7 SDK. I have not found any luck. Please point me to the right place where I can get the proper info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read [What's new in Windows Phone SDK 8.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206940%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) - it give you all, what you need.

Exactly for controls:

> Windows Phone 8 features the following new controls:
>
> - Windows Phone 8 includes a LongListSelector control that you can use to group, display, and scroll through long lists of data. It also
>     provides a mechanism for users to jump to a specific section of a
>     list.
> - In Windows Phone 8, Pivot and Panorama controls have been removed from the SDK and are now located in the phone’s read-only memory
>     (ROM). This way your app can use a separate native input thread, which
>     means a significant increase in the input responsiveness of these
>     controls. The working set memory of the Panorama control also has been
>     reduced.
> - The WebBrowser control is now based on Internet Explorer 10, which offers HTML5 and expanded CSS support for richer in-browser
>     experiences.
> - The performance of the ProgressBar control has been improved. You should use this control to report value-based or indeterminate
>     progress.

I hope my answer will be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

there is lost of API changes instead of UI,
You can refer the below mentioned URL for the same.

[Download pdf poster Windows Phone API Quick Start](http://cmsresources.windowsphone.com/devcenter/en-us/downloads/064028-microsoft-poster.pdf)

Hope it helps